# ios push controller view programmatically without storyboards or xib

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

In ViewControllerA I have a table with three rows of data right now (three messages).  Clicking on a row, I'm trying to push to ViewControllerB with the text from one of the rows (the name).  Problem I'm having is I'm trying to do everything programmatically, not using storyboard ids or storyboard segues.  Is this possible?  Here's what I have.

ViewControllerA m.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  Messages *cell = (Messages *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSString *from = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.from.text];
  ViewControllerB *VCB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
  VCB.from = from;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:VCB animated:YES];
  //using this^ creates a new view controller with a black screen but passes the variable
  //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushMessage" sender:self];
  using this^ shows my ViewControllerB perfectly but the value isn't set
}
```

ViewControllerB h.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *from;
```

ViewControllerB m.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog(@"%@", from);
}
```

Is there a way to do this without initiating a new viewcontrollerB in VCA and getting the right push animation?

Comment: You are asking if you can push a viewController, with out initializing a viewController and with out using storyboards/xibs?

Comment: I have the ViewControllerB in my storyboard...but I wanted to try to go away from using storyboards/xibs.  I want to try and do it all programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I understand what you're asking and you are almost on the right track here. You said that it works when you use `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushMessage" sender:self];` but the value is not set.

So, declare an NSString "from" in your header and in the previous code delete the `[self.navigationController pushViewController:CVC animated:YES];`

```
//ViewControllerA.h

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *from;



//ViewControllerA.m

@synthesize from;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Messages *cell = (Messages *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  from = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.from.text];

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushMessage" sender:self];
}
```

Then you need to use the `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

```
 //ViewControllerA.m

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushMessage"]) {

        ViewControllerB *vcb = [segue destinationViewController];

        [vcb setFrom:[self from]];
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT**

Well, I feel like this is a really wrong way to do it. But, this will satisfy all of your conditions asked in the question. I have checked and this does in fact work:

First, Go to your storyboard, click on the View Controller B, click on the identity inspector and change the Storyboard ID. Also click the check that says "Use Storyboard ID".

[image: Identity Inspector]

In your ViewControllerA:

```
//ViewControllerA.h

- (void)callViewControllerWithCellString:(NSString *)str;

//ViewControllerA.m

- (void)callViewControllerWithCellString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    SecondViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];
    [vc setFrom:str];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Messages *cell = (Messages *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *from = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.from.text];

    [self callViewControllerWithCellString:from];
}
```

Comment: I think he mentioned that he wanted to do this without using storyboards

Comment: @KarimLanguedoc yeah thats what I was confused about. I did notice that he said he was trying to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` though and that he said it did work just didn't set the string value

Comment: Sorry for not answering for a while...Karim is correct, I wanted to do this without using storyboards.  I did have a typo in the question of VCB CVC...

Comment: @denikov from what I'm reading you do have a storyboard though? At least from your comment to Hermann. Why don't you want to pass the data through the storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.  Is that possible to do?  Like I said in the other comments, it looks like in my didSelectRow method, in order to use pushViewController, you have to alloc and init...so it's creating a new one, when I already have one in my storyboard.  Does that make sense?  Is there a way to push to the B controller which I already have without using segue identifiers?

Comment: @denikov Yes, you can achieve this by following the code above and using a segue identifier. I know you're saying that you don't want to transfer the data through segues. But, part of the whole reason for a storyboard is to link the connections between the different controllers. As defined by Apple: "A storyboard is a visual representation of the user interface of an iOS application, showing screens of content and the connections between those screens."

Comment: I know I'm being stubborn here, but...if I wanted to do it without segues, would I have to initialize the entire ViewControllerB and all of it's contents in ViewControllerA?

Comment: @denikov look at my edit. Thats how you would do it without segues

Comment: @Zack Thanks, but what I did was just programmatically set up my second view controller.  Remember, I asked to do it without storyboards.  I deleted the view controller from my storyboard and initialized everything in my viewDidLoad method.  Now the variable gets passed and I have everything in there.  Thanks again for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

So lets see if i understand this.

1. You want the text from the clicked row passed to the view controller that you want to present
2. You want to do this without using storyboards

Sounds simple enough.  Check this out.

```
// I actually recommend this option
// Simply initialize your view controller with the text that you want to pass
ViewControllerB * VCB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithText:from];

//  For this to work, you'll have to declare a new init method in your .h file like this
-(void)initWithText:(NSSTring *)text;

// You should also declare an iVar to store your text
NSString * fromText;

// and implement it in your .m file like this
-(void)initWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        fromText = text;
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

```
// Or, you could do this. 
// In ViewControllerB.h, create a property
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * fromText;

// In ViewControllerB.m, synthesize it
@synthesize fromText;

// Then you can pass that property a value like this
ViewControllerB * VCB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
VCB.fromText = from;
```

Comment: Thanks for that advice.  The problem I seem to have is I have ViewControllerB in my storyboard already set up.  Based on the row which is clicked in A, I want to pass that variable to B and load data there.  Declaring VCB in A and pushing VCB gives me a black screen in the simulator...which I supposed means it created a NEW ViewControllerB...

Answer (score 1):

Variables shoudl be lower case.

Your ViewControllerB should be displaed. Do you create all view elements in there programatically too? If you don't then you better load it from a XIB or from the storyboard. You can do that without segueing to it.

But I guess it is much easer to overwrite the `perpareForSegue:` method and set the `from` property there. That is what perpareForSegue is made for when you need to do some customization programatically while using storyboards for all the easy stuff.

Comment: ViewControllerB is displayed.  If I use performSegueWithIdentifier, then ViewControllerB from my storyboard is displayed but the value isn't passed to it.  If I use pushViewController, it looks like it creates a new ViewControllerB with just a black screen...but the value is passed.

Comment: Yes, the way you create it and push it would display an empty view, because you do not load it from XIB or Storyboard. (You can load an individual view - of a controller - from storyboard.) As for the segue thing - please share some relevant code. In segue you should be able to pass custom data such as detail items or the `from` data in your case. But there you may run into an issue caused by the sequence of actions. Please share some code, including what you do with the `from` property within ViewControllerB.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should check your code. You are pushing a viewController named CVC onto the navigation controller. I assume this is a typo.

Did you override ViewControllerB  "initWithNibName:bundle:" as I see you are calling init. How would the ViewController know what nib to load if you didn't?

Also, it is recommended that you call [super viewDidLoad] in your viewDidLoad call.

Answer (score 1):

You can push views programmatically as well.
You seem to do following

```
ViewControllerB *VCB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
VCB.from = from;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:CVC animated:YES];
```

Which means you want to push VCB and not CVC. This change should fix your problem.
You can also put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` to verify your new ViewController is loaded.

If you are using storyboard for VCB as well, I think you should do following --

`ViewControllerB *VCB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCBIdentifier"];`

where `VCBIdentifier` is the identifier to your ViewControllerB marked in Identity Inspector -> StoryBoardID.
With your current init, I think, it is creating a default viewcontroller which is blank/empty.

Comment: It was a typo...but when pushing the view controller, I think it makes a new one, ViewControllerB which I already have initialized, you understand what I mean?

Comment: Added more information specific to storyboard instantiation, this should solve your problem

Comment: You are correct.  For a future project, I want to do away with storyboards so programmatically it was creating a blank viewcontroller.  To fix that, I programmatically added all the information on the new viewcontroller and deleted the storyboard viewcontroller.  Now it works